# How can we decide between using unittest.main(), test suite or instantiating object and running method?

Tags: python

Hello I am having couple of ways to run unittest.

1. Use unittest.main() :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

2. Suite:

```
def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_default_widget_size'))
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_widget_resize'))
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

3. Object instantiation:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Obj = WidgetTestCase()
    Obj.methodname() # this can either be one of test methods or a method that invokes multiple test methods.
```

Why do we have many ways to do the same thing? How to decide which approach to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of granularity and ease-of-use.

The main() is the simplest and popular form. You just run your module and It discovers for you all the tests and you don’t have to do nothing.

The other methods give you more control of what exactly to test.